# Cross product and reading headers in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, header, similarity, cross-product

i have some hadoop document similarity project that i'm working on, and i'm stuck in some part. The situation looks like this(I have a document term index table stored in a csv file

"",  t1,t2,t3,t4,....

---

doc1,f11,f12,f13,f14,....

doc2,f21,f22,f23,f24,....

doc3,f31,f32,f33,f34,....

.

.

.

where f12 means the frequency of term2(t2) in document1(doc1)

On the other hand, I have a query file contains the queries that need to be searched for their nearest or similar documents

"",  t1,t3,t122,t34,....

---

q1,f11,f12,f13,f14,....

q2,f21,f22,f23,f24,....

q3,f31,f32,f33,f34,....

.

.

.
but here the terms here may contains different terms, so i need to find the cross product of these two (term index and query) in order to find the distances between the query and th existing document

The problem contains two parts:
**first**, how to read the headers of each of these csv files to store them in some termvector considering the file will be splitted into different machines.

**second**, how to make the cross product on these two files, in order to find the similartiy(create a new document that can have all the possible terms(dimensions) in order to find the similarity)

I'm planning to write some K-nearest neighbour algorithm to find the similarity
Which tool or tools should i use, Pig,Hive,Mahout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a separate chapter on the book [MapReduce Design Patterns](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920025122.do) on Cartesian product, with source code given.

Comment: Source code is also available here: https://github.com/adamjshook/mapreducepatterns/tree/master/MRDP/src/main/java/mrdp/ch5

Answer (score 1):

Yes for @vefthym answer and I have been reading the same chapter in same book!

HOWEVER, the runtime is incredibly long! Following the way in the book, for a 600kb datasets containing 20,000 records, running cartesian product takes over 10hrs! Although I know for 20,000 records, the computation would be nearly 200m times and the I/O access would be 400m times, which is huge, I feel it is impractical for it to work on a big dataset amounting to GB or TB.

I am contacting the author to see if he got the same runtime. Will let you guys know

Comment: Did you get any answer?

Comment: @vefthym Yes and No. I went through the examples mentioned in the book. However, there are sort of crude implementation of cross product join using a technique called Block Nested Loop. However, this posed a questions that the Block need to be transferred in the cluster to order for other Block cross-joining with it, which cause a lot burden on the network. I am trying Pig [link](http://pig.apache.org) since I was told Pig has some optimization on the cross product join. I had a colleague who used Pig to process some data whose size is as big as TB within couple of hours.

Comment: I have used blocked nested loop in Hadoop and it is very practical, but a little bit slow. However, you can find a good approximation in this research paper (I am not the author) http://www.cs.utah.edu/~lifeifei/papers/mrknnj.pdf